# How can assign a string from a pointed array to a struct using for loops?

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

Basic, my problem is here:

```
(*(char *) &aluno.nome) = *lista_alunos[i-1];
```

the code above return just the first element.

and the code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alunos {

    int id;
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
};

int main()
{

    struct alunos aluno;
    char var_struct[50] = {0};
    char *lista_alunos[] = {
        {"Mauricio"},
        {"Jose"}
        };

    memcpy(&aluno, var_struct, 50);
    for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
        (*(int *) &aluno.id) = i;
        (*(char *) &aluno.nome) = *lista_alunos[i-1];
        printf("Entrou no for\n");
        printf("%u\n", aluno.id);
        printf("%s\n", aluno.nome);
        // ((int) *&alunos)[i] = (struct alunos) {i, &lista_alunos[i-1] , 33};
    };
    return 0;
}
```

i resolved with this:

```
        sprintf(aluno.nome, lista_alunos[i-1]);
```

this is the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct alunos {

    int id;
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
};

int main()
{

    struct alunos aluno;
    char *lista_alunos[] = {
        {"Mauricio"},
        {"Jose"}
        };

    for(int i=1;i<3;i++){
        aluno.id = i;
        sprintf(aluno.nome, lista_alunos[i-1]);

    };
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to copy c-style strings (that are trusted to be short enough).

Comment: `memcpy(&aluno, var_struct, 50);` will not do anything useful, and not even initialize the full structure. Perhaps you wanted to do e.g. `memset(&aluno, 0, sizeof aluno)`? Then just do `struct alunos aluno = { 0 };` instead. And `(*(int *) &aluno.id) = i` is the same as `aluno.id = i`.

Comment: Also, the `printf` format `%u` is for **`unsigned int`**, while `aluno.id` is a (`signed`) `int`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type is actually *undefined behavior*.

Comment: thanks everyone, but didnt work. @MikeCAT strcpy not for this.

i resolved the question with 'sprintf':

        sprintf(aluno.nome, lista_alunos[i-1]);

Comment: `sprintf(aluno.nome, lista_alunos[i-1]);` has a risk. Consider what will hapen when `lista_alunos[i-1]` contains `%`. It should be `sprintf(aluno.nome, "%s", lista_alunos[i-1]);`.

Comment: tnks @MikeCAT! works fine!

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't do e.g. `strcpy(aluno.nome, lista_alunos[i-1])`?

Comment: And please start loops iterating over arrays with `0`, so you don't have to do something like `i-1`.

Comment: Humm..... do u copied and tried that? i did and didnt work. I dont know why this actually happens, but it happens. maybe because of pointers. really dont know.

by the way.... the loop with 0 is just because i dont want to set i+1 at the ID.

thnks 'one more time'!

Comment: That's weird, using `strcpy` [works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/j9WoWfbGo).

Comment: sorry about that. when i tried before, probably had more things wrong.
now, because of u, i tried again and did work. thannnnks a lot! @Someprogrammerdude